# ASP.NET MVC: How to bind an object property to an HTML attribute

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

Here is my dummy model:

```
class Customer {
    string Name;

    // View Model part
    bool IsDisabled;
}
```

Here is my view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(actionName, controllerName))
{
   @Html.TextBoxFor( c => c.Name, new { disabled = ***) })

   <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

So the question is: How can i bind the 'isDisabled' property of my viewmodel to the 'disabled' attribute of my textbox? i.e. What should stand in the place of '***' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.Name, Model.IsDisabled ? new { disabled = "disabled" } : null)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@Html.TextBoxFor( c => c.Name, new { disabled = c.IsDisabled) })
```

Comment: Well, first of all, if you try to run it, you will get a runtime error. Furthermore in plain HTML, you can't write <input disabled="true" or disabled="false".